# relative pathnames in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

Consider:

```
<xsl:result-document 
    href="{string-join(
              ($scripts-offset, $metadata-directory, $redirect-file),
              '/'
           )}" 
    format="text">
```

in which the net effect of the string-join is "../resources/foo.txt".

What is this supposed to be relative to?  The style sheet? The input document?

**EDIT**

Cher answerers: after posing this question, I had a burst of energy and coffee and read the spec for xs:result-document carefully, and I also read the implementation of Saxon-B. The spec calls for the href to be relative to the 'primary output document'. Depending on how you call Saxon, it might set that up correctly from the File object you supply it as a target ... or it might require you to make an extra call to set it up. So upvotes all around, and sorry for all the trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [implementation defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-implementation-defined).

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-result-trees

> The `href` attribute is optional. The
>   default value is the zero-length
>   string. The effective value of the
>   attribute must be a URI Reference,
>   which may be absolute or relative.
>   There may be implementation-defined
>   restrictions on the form of absolute
>   URI that may be used, but the
>   implementation is not required to
>   enforce any restrictions. Any legal
>   relative URI must be accepted. Note
>   that the zero-length string is a legal
>   relative URI.
>
> The base URI of the document node at
>   the root of the final result tree is
>   based on the effective value of the
>   `href` attribute. If the effective value
>   is a relative URI, then it is resolved
>   relative to the base output URI. If
>   the implementation provides an API to
>   access final result trees, then it
>   must allow a final result tree to be
>   identified by means of this base URI.

And from http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-base-output-uri

> This document does not specify any
>   application programming interfaces or
>   other interfaces for initiating a
>   transformation. This section, however,
>   describes the information that is
>   supplied when a transformation is
>   initiated. Except where otherwise
>   indicated, the information is
>   required.
>
> - A base output URI. [Definition:  The    **base output URI** is a URI to
>     be used as the base URI when resolving a relative URI allocated to a final
>     result tree. If the transformation generates more than one final result tree, then typically each one will be allocated a URI relative to this base 
>     URI. ] The way in which a base output URI is established is implementation-defined.

But more important, think about this note:

> **Note:**
>
> The base URI of the final result tree
>   is not necessarily the same thing as
>   the URI of its serialized
>   representation on disk, if any. For
>   example, a server (or browser client)
>   might store final result trees only in
>   memory, or in an internal disk cache.
>   As long as the processor satisfies
>   requests for those URIs, it is
>   irrelevant where they are actually
>   written on disk, if at all.

Comment: Not according to http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document it's not implementation-defined. It's specifically tied to the primary output doc.

Comment: The base URI of the document node at the root of the final result tree is based on the effective value of the href attribute. If the effective value is a relative URI, then it is resolved relative to the base output URI. If the implementation provides an API to access final result trees, then it must allow a final result tree to be identified by means of this base URI.

Comment: @bmargulies: Yes, that's my quote. And then I also quote **base output URI** definition. Did you read it?

Comment: @Ale OK, yes, implementation defined. I capitulate.

Answer (score 1):

In Saxon and AltovaXML it's relative to path from XSLT processor were called. For example:

```
cd somePath

java -classpath lib\saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -o:output.xml xml\input.xml xsl\stylesheet.xsl

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Altova\AltovaXML2011\AltovaXML.exe" -xslt2 xsl\stylesheet.xsl -in xml\input.xml -out output.xml
```

In your case it would be:

```
somePath\..\resources\foo.txt
```

Comment: Except when it's not. With Saxon-B 9.x, I just laboriously determined that, if you use Trax and there's a system ID available on the output, it will (as per the spec) use that system ID.